# Wix ICE Error from 01 to 07

Tags: tfs, wix, tfs-2015, vnext

I have to update our build-system from the old "XML-System" to the newer vNext.
Now I have the problem, that in a build progress, I'm getting errormessages from ligther.exe:

### [error]light.exe(0,0): Error LGHT0217: Error executing ICE action 'ICE01'. ...

up to ICE07.
And at the end:

### [error]light.exe(0,0): Error LGHT0216: An unexpected Win32 exception with error code 0x643 occurred: Action - 'ICE09' Fatal error during installation

When I make the same build with the "old" XML-Version it works without any problems, any ideas?

Thanks a lot.
Kriz

Answer (score 3):

According to the error prompting message:  `An unexpected Win32 exception with error code 0x643 occurred: Action - 'ICE09' Fatal error during installation`

It's probably a permissions problem with validation. You could try to give the build service account more privileges such as local administrator permission on the build agent.

Besides, there are no tools to convert XAML build definition to vNext directly, so please double check you have manually created fully in a accord.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this issue only on the build machine, where the build task has no admin rights.
I didn't saw this on my developer machine, where I have admin rights. This error is written by the [light.exe](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html), which is the *Windows Installer XML linker* contained in the *Wix Toolset*.

In order to solve this I suppressed validation of the light.exe. This can be done in two different ways:

**On the commandline of light.exe**

```
-sval
```

**On the commandline, when using WixSharp**

```
Compiler.LightOptions = "-sval";
```